# Building ServiceStack.Core for open-source project

Tags: servicestack, .net-core

We are developing an Open-Source aPaaS product. The project is in its very early stage.

We use .NETCore, for Web Services, we want to use ServiceStack.

For now, we are using NuGet packages. But, the number of service operations have started to go up and exceed the limit of 10.

We tried to download the Servicestack .netcore source code from GitHub (both ServiceStack/tree/master and netcore branches) but it is failing to build. Following are the errors we get:

1. `E:\user\Downloads\Ss\ServiceStack-master\src\ServiceStack.Client\error CS0006: Metadata file 'E:\user\Downloads\Ss\ServiceStack-master\src\ServiceStack.Interfaces\bin\PclDebug\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll' could not be found`
2. `E:\user\Downloads\Ss\ServiceStack-master\src\ServiceStack\error CS0006: Metadata file 'E:\user\Downloads\Ss\ServiceStack-master\src\ServiceStack.Client\bin\Debug\netstandard1.6\ServiceStack.Client.dll' could not be found`